# TextMate alpha doesn't recognize Python grammar

Tags: python, macos, bundle, textmate

After the last alpha update, I can't find a way to use Python syntax in a file. If I press 
command:, the menu doesn't include Python.  If I pull up the "hub" on the bottom bar to the right of the tab-definition pull down, Python is present. I've deleted and re-added Python bundles, restarted TextMate, to no avail.  When I go to edit bundle, in the python window, the language grammar is empty of content.

I've looked at the documentation, the blogs, etc. and haven't found how to fix this. 
Thanks in advance to those in the know!

Comment: The [textmate users](http://lists.macromates.com/listinfo/textmate) mailing list is probably a better venue for this sort of question, especially since textmate2 is still alpha. Reinstalling may help as well (bundles are stored in ~/Library/Application Support/Textmate/Managed/Bundles).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [mailing list](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2014-April/037293.html):

> […] try Preferences → Bundles and uncheck/check the Python bundle.
>
> There is an issue with updating bundles (in current release build) where if TM is terminated  while updating a bundle, it can leave a broken bundle on disk (partially deleted), which could manifest itself as some actions being no-op (although deleting `~/Library/Caches` should have made deleted actions disappear from the menu).